# Network is not applicable in Visual Studio 2015 for Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, profiling

I've created Console Application in Visual Studio 2015 Professional for simple HttpWebRequest. I'd like to monitor raw HTTP traffic which is sent or received by my Application. As I understand there is Performance Profiler in Visual Studio 2015 for this purpose (Alt+F2).

But Network checkbox is in Not applicable tools group. Is there any way for using this tool for Console Application?

Comment: You can trace all System.Net activity but it can be  hard to read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN, this tool is only used for monitoring HTTP network operations made through the `WinRT HttpClient API`, and as explicitly stated in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/05/04/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/),

> Operations made using the old .NET HttpClient API aren’t captured.

So the answer is no.

You can use [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I thought Fiddler can monitor only HTTP traffic, but just now I've read that HTTPS supported also.